# Access 2016 Type Conversion Errors at Hours in Time without Date when importing csv files

Tags: csv, ms-access, types

Thank you for reading my input.

I have .csv file imported into ACCESS table.

The Time with Date type was selected for "02:00:00" fields, which is long time data indicates hours and minutes of elapsed time.

Some of the data are converted perfectly, but about 1% of my total rows are listed in the failure table.

May I have some advices on identifying the error, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *IsDate* to identify "bad" times:

```vb
If IsDate([TextTimeField]) Then
    ' Good time.
Else
    ' No time.
End If
```

Or link the CSV file *as is*, and run a query:

```
Select *, IsDate([TextTimeField]) As TimeOK
From YourLinkedCsvTable
```